# What am I supposed to pass to cloudinary from formidable, I tried the image path/name that didnt work

Tags: javascript, next.js, multipartform-data, cloudinary, formidable

I have the following parse of a stream in Next JS that is getting the file input for an image, it looks like it stores the image for me to pass to cloudinary but cloudinary says the image doesnt exist.

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./upload";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
    const path = files.image.path + "/" + files.image.name
       cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, function (error, result) {
      console.log(result, error);
    });
  });
```

Here's the image path and name from the parse

```
{"image":{"size":35168,"path":"./upload/1547db49054ff2a2acb915a03","name":"test.png","type":"image/png","mtime":"2021-03-12T03:46:20.002Z"}}
```

and heres the error from cloudinary

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './upload/7e1c5b9e3235ae38d12097300/test.png'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './upload/7e1c5b9e3235ae38d12097300/test.png'
}
```

I must be missin something fundamental here.

UPDATE: I have tried writing to with fs, but still having no luck. dont quite get it. Is the image ever saved for so I can pass it to cloudinary.

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));

    console.log(files.image.path);

    var oldPath = files.image.path;
    var newPath = path.join(__dirname, "upload") + "/" + files.image.name;
    var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

    fs.writeFile(newPath, rawData, function (err) {
      console.log(newPath);
      const path = newPath;
      cloudinary.uploader.upload(path, function (error, result) {
        console.log(result, error);
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has this problem you can pass the buffer which is the rawData variable and works like so

```
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(files));

    console.log(files.image.path);

    var oldPath = files.image.path;
    var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

    console.log(rawData);

    let cld_upload_stream = cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(
      {
        folder: "sick-fits"
      },
      function(error, result) {
          console.log(error, result);
      }
  );

  streamifier.createReadStream(rawData).pipe(cld_upload_stream);
```